# How to fix "permission denied" error on online server?

Tags: php, file-io

I have this very simple php website, [Projectx2](http://www.projectx2.zzl.org) that I am hosting from the [Zymic](http://www.zymic.com) server because it had good ratings.

However, I am having a few unusual errors that don't happen on my locally hosted [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org) server.

The errors are:

> **Warning** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/zzl.org/p/r/o/projectx2/htdocs/default.php:259) in **/www/zzl.org/p/r/o/projectx2/htdocs/default.php** on line **295**.

and:

> **Warning:** fopen (count.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in **/www/zzl.org/p/r/o/projectx2/htdocs/default.php** on line **298**

and:

> **Warning:** fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in **/www/zzl.org/p/r/o/projectx2/htdocs/default.php** on line **299**.

and:

> **Warning:** fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in **/www/zzl.org/p/r/o/projectx2/htdocs/default.php** on line **300**.

Here, I have a simple counter that keeps page counts in the file `count.txt`, which is also on the server.

Here is my code from 290 - 302:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('count.txt','r');
    $count = fread($fp,filesize('count.txt'));
    fclose($fp);
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['count'])) {
        setcookie('count');   // 295
        $count++;
    }
    $fp = fopen('count.txt','w'); // 298
    fwrite($fp,$count);           // 299
    fclose($fp);                  // 300
    echo "<div id='hitcount'>$count views</div>";
?>
```

I don't know why this is happening - I know very little about I/O in PHP, but I know some in Java. Can you please explain to me the problems in this code, and why it only works on a regular server?

Or maybe, is it just the Zymic server?

Tell me if I need to reveal more information or code.

thanks.

Comment: _Permission denied_ is usually a sign that you don't have permission. Subsequent errors flow from this.

Comment: what im asking is: how do I get the permission?

Comment: Talk to your hosting company or you may be able to set permissions to a folder through whatever means they provide (cpanel, ftp, RDP, SSH, whatever).  Is it a Linux Host?  How are you copying files to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One by one:

*Cannot modify header information - headers already sent*: indicates that the PHP script is attempting to modify the HTTP headers after it has already started emitting the page. I can't give any more information because you haven't posted the relevant code.

*Permission denied* means the web server user does not have permission to access the file in the way that you wish. Talk to your hosting company about how you grant that permission. All the subsequent errors flow from this problem.

*critique my website design*: No - this site is about focussed questions on software development, not opinions on layout or colour schemes.

Comment: The first point I understand now - I have already started printing out content. The second point I'll follow. I'll keep in mind that third quote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a FTP client like FileZilla to connect to your your website and then find the file `count.txt` and right click and then -> properties and set the permission to `0777`

Comment: do you know what `0777` means?

Comment: Some hosting systems will not permit 0777 because of its security risk. This is a sledgehammer approach to granting permission, and gives the sledge hammer to any would-be hacker who stumbles across it.

Comment: 0777 = allows anyone full read/write to that file for php - BUT this is bad idea. Try using something like `0666` if it fails, use `0777`.

Comment: Avoid `0777` (if you can) that gives out way too much permissions.  Generally `0755` or `0744` will work out well enough. Even less on files that don't need to be executed: `0644`